# FSCalendar date align above other dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, fscalendar

I have been using FSCalendar in a project for a while, and after iOS 13 I had this bug where I have the calendar views like this after scrolling right or left. I don't know why but the calendar changes to 2026 automatically but the value is still 2019.

[image]

I'm using the latest version of FSCalendar. Anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? I do not know where to start to find the issue that caused this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by adding the calendar to the class like this `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FSCalendar *calendar;`
 and force it to reload after the view appears.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [_calendar reloadData];
    [_calendar.calendarHeaderView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: After wasting two hours on this, I'm glad this worked for me.